# POVRay doesn't show object behind difference

Tags: povray

I have a [POVRayfile which creates this cone using Mesh2](https://pastebin.com/aC5aQCg1):

[image]

and I would like to cut a piece out of it, so I can see inside. For this I'm using an intersection with these 3 boxes:

```
union {
    box {    <0,0,0>     <-100,-100,100>
        texture {
            pigment {
            color
            <1,0,0> 
            } 
        } 
    }
    box {<0,0,0>        <100,-100,100>
        texture {
            pigment {
            color
            <1,0,0> 
            } 
        } 
    }
    box { <0,0,0>        <-100,100,100>
            texture {
            pigment {
            color
            <1,0,0> 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

which then looks like this ([file](https://pastebin.com/q5fZnHqu)):
[image]

The part I wanted to get rid of is "gone", but it's not transparent. How do I make POV-Ray look into the cone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intersections are not meant for this. They are designed to cut into a solid body (and thus create a new surface).

You have to use the "clipped_by" property. More details here:

[link](http://news.povray.org/povray.newusers/thread/%3Cweb.5ab8f1a5c715f2fdd8a52b4d0@news.povray.org%3E//povray.newusers/thread/%3C5ab92ee5@news.povray.org%3E/)